# How I can replace the micro switch for my club car?

Tags: switches

I used the [micro switch](https://www.grandye-switch.com/product/club-car-micro-switch/) in my club car, does somebody know how I can replace this for my old one?

I bought the switch from Zing ear.

Comment: 1.  What's a "club car?" 2. You "used" the micro switch.  Is it one time use only? 3. You seem to have already found a replacement.  Where's the problem in installing the new one?

Comment: @JRE google shows golf carts

Comment: That switch has two mounting holes that likely has small bolts or rivets going through them (rivets can be replaced with bolts).  The connectors are likely push on receptacles, which can be pulled off the old switch and pushed on the new.

Comment: It might help if you provide a picture of how the old switch is currently mounted. The connectors can probably be easily moved to the new switch.